# Could an infinite loop be created in Outlook using Contact Groups?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

This question is just out of curiosity.

I know that Contact Groups can be nested to form groups-within-groups, but will an infinite loop be created if the first group is nested again later?

Example:

Group 1(2) -> Group 2(3) -> Group 3(1)

3 is nested in 2, 2 is nested in 1, and 1 is nested in 3.

My internet searches so far have only yielded instructions for nesting, nothing about potential loops.

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @Steven, I was reluctant to try it while working, but did anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an infinite loop cannot be created in Outlook using nested Groups.

However, the individual groups can be infinitely expanded out by clicking the [+] icons.

I tested the exact Group structure given in the question twice with one email address per group (the same address). I received a single email both times and came to these conclusions:

1) The Application has some built in exception handling to prevent a loop, or

2) The Application filters out duplicate recipients, or

3) A combination of 1 and 2. I think it probably does a little of both.

I'll test it later with 3 unique email addresses and report what happens.